# Disable GIFs system-wide or by app

Tags: images, accessibility

I was wondering if there is some way to:

1. Disable GIFs from loading, and/or
2. Disable GIFs from playing on an Android device.

The first would be mostly to conserve data, especially if I'm on Tumblr or a similar site where GIFs feature prominently. The second would be for accessibility (for example, a friend who is epileptic).

Maybe it could be done through editing the app, or through an Xposed module?

If it helps, I have a Galaxy S4 Verizon, rooted.

Comment: Am not 100% sure, as gifs being played from websites, would suggest you're viewing through the web browser - that code to display the gif is embedded in the webpage being downloaded, in short, you're putting yourself in a no-win situation where to override the web page currently downloaded and blocking the gifs on the fly. Have not seen such thing due to one reason alone, the web-browser is running in a sandboxed process and any attempt to cross that boundary would end up getting killed by the kernel for violation of process boundaries.

Comment: Unless, there is a proxy server in place, in which the proxy can strip out the gifs from the webpage and at the same time your web browser is pointing to the said proxy server, it may be feasible.

Comment: But are you OK with a regular image (non-GIF)?

Comment: The AOSP "had" this option: http://www.guidingtech.com/11294/android-ics-browser-awesome-little-known-things-to-do/ I say had because I couldn't find the setting in the AOSP Browser app on Google Play.

Comment: This is possible in desktop Chrome, using Chrome extensions (see [How to stop animated gifs in Google Chrome?](http://superuser.com/questions/23655/)), but unfortunately Chrome for Android doesn't support extensions, and Google have no current announced plans on extension support in the future: [Chrome Mobile FAQ](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/faq)

Comment: Geffchang - I'd prefer all other images to load but gif, especially since a lotnof sites these days use images for navigation buttons and such. I did find that Opera Mini has a built in feature that stops gifs from loading, so for now it works for what i need. Any other methods would be welcome, though!